# Are one-dimensional maps still called the same if they involve multiple functions instead of one recurrent function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

Is the definition of a one-dimensional function necessarily something generated by x=f(x) or can a series of functions f,g,etc. be applied? Or is that called a different name?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what definition of (one-dimensional) function are you referring to? See iterated function system (IFS), or piecewise smooth functions.

Comment: Thanks. Let me give you an example: from what I understand, a reiteration of cos(x) constitutes a difference equation or, more precisely, a one-dimensional map (but correct me if my terminology is not accurate). If so, would a series of functions, let's say a series like cos-sin-cos-cos-cos-sin(x) still qualify as the reiteration above as a one-dimensional map?

Comment: What you mean is a fixed-point iteration. And the second thing you describe sounds like an IFS and the associated chaos game, they are one method to draw fractals like the Sierpinsky triangle, fern fractal, etc. In one dimension the Cantor set can be constructed/approximated that way.

Comment: Thanks, very useful. Can I ask a quick follow-up question: what if the functions applied are not from a specified 'sequence of functions' but any known and randomly picked functions. Is it still IFS/chaos game?

Comment: No, that would lose all structure, you could get any sequence of points out of that, and potentially any real number as limit point.

Comment: Thanks. Last question I promise: does this fall under some other name? (so that I can look into it more), or it's just a 'random sequence of functions', plain and simple.

Comment: That is just common sense, there is no name for an absence of structure. For something that has a little more structure you might look into different ergodic properties, and the ideas connected to them, Markov chains, (discrete) stochastic processes,...

Comment: ok thanks! very helpful